# Add rows for dataframe based on column

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have dataframe

```
mydf <- data.frame(userid = c("1"),gender = c("boy girl boy"), dob = c("25-Mar-2016 02-Nov-2013 12-Nov-2014") )
```

I need to add and split like this

```
                userid gender dob
            1      1    boy 25-Mar-2016
            2      1   girl 02-Nov-2013
            3      1    boy 12-Nov-2014
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `library(dplyr); mydf %>% mutate_at(vars(-userid), funs(strsplit(as.character(.), ' '))) %>% unnest()`

Comment: Thanks Sotos. Was really helpful !

Comment: the `data.table` one is even simpler... `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(i) unlist(strsplit(i, ' ')))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a split on the second and third column by space, `append` the 'userid' column with the `list` and convert to `data.frame`

```
lst <- lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " ")))
cbind(userid = mydf[,1], data.frame(lst, stringsAsFactors= FALSE))
#  userid gender         dob
#1      1    boy 25-Mar-2016
#2      1   girl 02-Nov-2013
#3      1    boy 12-Nov-2014
```

Comment: As I understand it the user id has to be the same for the split data.

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Was really helpful !